# Load script from memory in C

Tags: c, unix, execve

I have a script starting with a shebang stored in a string. I would like to execute this script without writing it in a temporary file.

I saw that `execve` takes a filename as argument. Is it possible to do the same with a script in memory.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. However, you could pipe the string to an interactive version of the script-interpreter.

Comment: And also be very, _very_ careful.

Comment: Where do you want stdout and stderr from your script to go?

Comment: I would like to use output of the script into my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script is not directly executable, when executing a script, the kernel identify which interpreter to launch then pass the file name as an argument to the interpreter, in your case a shell.

Should you want to execute a script stored in a string, you might directly launch the shell of your choice and pass your string as its standard input through a pipe.

Here is way to do it using [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html#tag_16_364):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  FILE *fp;
  char *prefix="/bin/bash <<'%EOF%'\n";
  char *script="#!/bin/bash\necho foo\ndate\n";
  char *suffix="%EOF%\n";
  char *command;
  char buf[1024];

  command=malloc(strlen(prefix)+strlen(script)+strlen(suffix)+1);
  sprintf(command,"%s%s%s",prefix,script,suffix);
  fp=popen(command, "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", buf);
  }
  pclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say that the script starts with a shebang string, you cannot directly pipe it into the standard input of a shell. But you can mimic what a shell would have done:

- extract the *shell command* from the shebang line
- start it with a pipe as standard input
- pipe the remaining of the script into that *shell command*

A more generalist version would control whether the script string starts with a `#!`. If it does, use the above way, else just pipe the whole string into an instance of `/bin/sh` (or whatever shell you are used to)

Comment: Piping the shebang line to the interpreter would be harmless as it would be ignored as a comment, which it is too. There is then no need to strip it from the passed string.

Comment: @jlliagre: I know it is common in Unix world that interpretors use `#` as the beginning of a comment. But the shebang could be used to any interpretor, for example the PostgreSQL one (`psql`) for which the comments are supposed to start with two dashes (`--`). Unsure whether it will accept the shebang line...

Comment: When the kernel executes a script, it passes the filename to the interpreter without stripping the first line. I would be surprised for an interpreter to fail when passed the shebang line as its standard input but I get your point.